# where can I catch the db connection exception in session mode: sqlserver?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I set up the session state using SQL Server. Everything works fine.

I am currently on my developer server, so I thought to disconnect the internet [the session db is online], to see what happens. Not surprisingly the famous yellow page of death occurred. Then I thought to catch this exception and I used :

```
try{
session["age"]= 25;
}catch
{ //log the exception here and continue}
```

but I was surprised that this will not cause any exception here; because the application will not contact the SQL Server at this stage.

It seems that when the IIS prepared the view page to show the user; it then contact the SQL Server to save the session information and if failed then it will throw that yellow page of death.

My question is:

is there any way to catch the exception in the code? Other than in `Global.asax`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session load/access happens at the beginning of the request lifecycle (`HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState` Event) and persisted back at the end of the request lifecycle (`HttpApplication.ReleaseRequestState` Event). It is not at the point where you'd get a value out of the session. To catch it, use an MVC Global Action Filter to handle exceptions, including the `SQLException` which will occur when this is the case. Alternatively, create an `HttpModule` to handle exception events.

In your `RegisterGlobalFilters` method (which is called by `Global.asax.cs`):

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters( GlobalFilterCollection filters )
    {
        filters.Add( new YourCustomExceptionHandlingAttribute } );
    }
}
```

And `YourCustomExceptionHandlingAttribute` should implement `HandleErrorAttribute`

Comment: nice answer, but it will be superb if it shows examples and code.. appreciating your time